# Changing Input to Output dynamically

Tags: c, input, output, microcontroller

I am using a STM32 Microcontroller and I need to change one Pin from Input to Output and then back to Input to start a communication with a sensor and so I can read out the data.

Is there any way to do that using STM32 HAL?

What would be the proper way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't use Cube/HAL nor Cube/LL, it's as simple as

```
#define MDIO_PORT  GPIOB  // MDIO is PB4
#define MDIO_PIN   4      //  -"-

MDIO_PORT->MODER |=  (0b01 << (2 * MDIO_PIN));  // change MDIO from Input to Output
MDIO_PORT->MODER &= ~(0b11 << (2 * MDIO_PIN));  // change MDIO from Output to Input
```

It's faster than the LL version as it omits the one extra unnecessary operation. Not to mention the HAL version...

Neither version is atomic, so this has to be borne in mind when the same GPIOx_MODER register is used in different interrupt levels (except in 'F1, where it could be made atomic by rewriting it to use bit-banding).

Comment: Funny we both took an example from an MDIO. One of the few cases where you need to do this.

Comment: I take no credit for that, I just couldn't come up with any reasonable example so simply took yours... :-) I remember only one case where I needed to switch between input and output, and that was due to badly designed hardware I could not change. Now switching between *AF* and input or output is more common, but that is another story.

Comment: It is net  it will not work if you want to change from analog mode to output for example. Clear first, then set

Comment: From Analog (0b11) to Output (0b01) it's one &, and to revert it it's one |. The only time you need two operations is switching between Output and AF. I'm not sure what did you mean by _net_.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the STM `LL` drivers, it can be as simple as this:

```c
    LL_GPIO_SetPinMode ( MDIO_GPIO_Port, MDIO_Pin, LL_GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT );
    LL_GPIO_SetPinMode ( MDIO_GPIO_Port, MDIO_Pin, LL_GPIO_MODE_INPUT );
```

You could look at what those macros/functions do if you wanted to just poke the bits manually (i.e. without the LL driver).

If you're using the HAL driver and don't want to "get your hands dirty" poking registers yourself, you'd have to faff about with stuff like:

```c
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = LCD_CS_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(LCD_CS_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);
```

I think using the HAL for simple GPIO pins is overkill, and I don't recommend it.

Comment: Okay right now I am using the HAL Libary because I need it for additional things. But I did not know there is a LL driver. I will look that up.

Thank you

Comment: If you open your `.ioc` file in STM32CubeIDE (or probably STM32CubeMX), click on the "Project Manager" tab at the top, then click "Advanced Settings", you can choose which driver to use for each peripheral. You can mix it up, and use LL for simple things like GPIO and timers, and HAL for more complex things like I2C. For example.